# Parsing mysql datetime to golang time

Tags: mysql, go

I have MySQL datetime in my table in the MySQL standard format like

> "2018-09-19 18:26:32.000000"

and when I try converting it ti golang time using `time.parse()` function, I get the error that

> parsing time "2018-09-19 18:26:32.000000": month out of range

I tried searching online and the format seems to be allowed and commonly used by many to successfully parse.

Can anyone help me with what I am missing? Below is the code snippet that I am using.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

layout := "2018-09-19 18:26:32.000000"
fmt.Println(val)
// prints 2018-09-19 18:26:32.000000
t, err := time.Parse(layout, val)
fmt.Println(fmt.Println(t.Unix()))
// prints -62135596800 
fmt.Println(err)
// prints parsing time "2018-09-19 18:26:32.000000": month out of range
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your layout is wrong, it should be `"2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000"`. The documentation states:

> Parse parses a formatted string and returns the time value it
>   represents. The layout defines the format by showing how the reference
>   time, defined to be
>
> Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006
>
> would be interpreted if it were the value; it serves as an example of the input format. The same interpretation will then be made to the input string.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    val := "2018-09-19 18:26:32.000000"
    layout := "2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000"
    t, _ := time.Parse(layout, val)
    fmt.Println(t.Unix()) // prints 1537381592
}
```

Outputs

```
1537381592
```

Try it [here](https://play.golang.org/p/c_IcIR4DUoT)